# Prevent water to accumulate in the frame gap

Tags: doors, door-frame

I recently replaced my garden door, and the new one has an outer frame.

The problem is that when it rains some water is held in the gap between the door and the frame, resulting in a "shower" when somebody opens the door or, worse, when it freezes, the door is ice-sealed to the frame. I am also concerned that over time this can damage the door, as the old one (frame less) was rotten due to the lack of proper protection and maintenance from the previous owner.

[image]

How can I prevent water to drip and remain there?

Comment: Can you include a picture showing a wider view?

Answer (score 3):

Consider a flashing installed above the frame that will deflect the water out and away from the doorway.